# worker.on('error') not working when unhandled rejection happens in the worker

Tags: node.js, async-await, worker-thread

**worker.js**

```js
async function main() {
  throw new Error('Bullocks!');
}

setTimeout(async () => {
  await main();
}, 1000);
```

**main.js**

```js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');
worker.on('error', err => {
  console.log('error happened on the worker');
});
```

Why that error handler on the main.js is not called, instead it just prints the error.

```
(node:26000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Bullocks!
```

I've used this solution and works: throwing the error when unhandled rejection happens, but is there any "proper" solution for this?

```js
async function main() {
  throw new Error('Bullocks!');
}

setTimeout(async () => {
  await main();
}, 1000);

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: Its inside settimeout,
once you set things inside settimeout they are going out of the scope.
your gonna need to use try/catch inside that settimeout to catch it and handle it.

Comment: I just tried puting the `main()` outside, still not working.

Comment: Still, your not catching it and not handling it.
if you throw an error you need to catch it and then do what ever u wish with it.
you can console.log it or if you dont catch it, it bubble up till it throw the process

Comment: If `main()` itself is returning a rejected promise, then you can just `.catch()` that and handle it.  If the unhandled rejection is inside of main and not propagated out, then you have to find where that is in the `main()` code and handle the error appropriately.  There is no substitute for writing correct error handling unless you want to just let the process/thread abort because of it.

Comment: I had the same problem and it's not a case of faulty error handling. Apparently this unexpected behavior is by design. It is discussed here in the nodejs issues log, along with a workaround: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33834